# Recurrence Relation from Old Exam

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I see this challenging recurrence relation that has a solution of $T^2(n)=\theta (n^2)$. anyone could solve it for me? how get it?

$$T(n)  = \begin{cases}  n,\quad &\text{        if n=1 or n=0 }\\
\sqrt{1/2[T^2(n-1)+T^2(n-2)]+}n   ,\quad   &\text{   if n>1} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, trying to parse your statement. Is $T(3) = \sqrt \frac{22}{7}$ ?

Comment: I get $T(2)=\sqrt{2.5}, T(3)=\sqrt{4.75}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:  Let $a(n)=T^2(n)$.  Then the recurrence relation becomes

$$a(n)={1\over2}a(n-1)+{1\over2}a(n-2)+n$$

with $a(0)=0$ and $a(n)=1$.  Now try finding $c$ and $C$ for which there's an inductive proof that $cn^2\lt a(n)\lt Cn^2$ for sufficiently large $n$.

**Added later** (at OP's request):  I'll do one inequality, which hopefully will show you how to do the other.

We'd like to find a constant $C$ such that $a(n-1)\lt C(n-1)^2$ and $a(n-2)\lt C(n-2)^2$ together imply $a(n)\lt Cn^2$.  If we just plug the assumed inequalities into what we know, we have

$$\begin{align}
a(n)&={1\over2}a(n-1)+{1\over2}a(n-2)+n\\
&\lt {1\over2}C(n-1)^2+{1\over2}C(n-2)^2+n\\
&={1\over2}C\big(n^2-2n+1+n^2-4n+4\big)+n\\
&=Cn^2+(1-3C)n+{5\over2}C
\end{align}$$

Keep in mind that this is all "scratch" work:  We're not writing up a proof at this point, nor are we trying to find the *exact* value of $C$ that gives the inequality, we're just trying to spot a value that will make things work.

The key is in the coefficient $(1-3C)$ in the last line.  If $C$ is big, that coefficient is negative, which will make the term $(1-3C)n$ hugely negative if $n$ is "sufficiently" large.  So let's pick a convenient value and see what happens.  Let's try $C=2$.

If you redo the derivation above with $C=2$, you wind up with

$$a(n)\lt 2n^2-5n+5\lt 2n^2\quad\text{if }n\ge2$$

since $5-5n$ is negative for $n\ge2$.

Note that any $C$ greater than ${1\over3}$ will make $1-3C$ negative, so you don't have to choose $C=2$.  It just happens to be convenient.  Something similar should happen when you look at the other inequality, $cn^2\lt a(n)$.  Give it a try!

Comment: Dear Barry, would you please add detail?

Comment: @MinaSoli, done!

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(n)=T^2(n)$  Then the recurrence is $S(n)=\frac 12(S(n-1)+S(n-2))+n$ [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%3DT%28n-1%29%2F2%2BT%28n-2%29%2F2%2Bn%2CT%280%29%3D0%2CT%281%29%3D1) $S(n)=\frac 13n^2+\frac {15}{27}n+\frac 2{27}-\frac 2{27\cdot 2^n}$

Comment: Dear Ross, would you please add more detail?

Comment: I just fed the relation to Alpha, as the link shows.  You can do the usual characteristic polynomial to see the homogeneous partis linear, and we know the sum over $n$ is roughly $n^2$, so the theta relation is right.

Comment: would you please add this detail to your solution ?

Comment: please learn me. is it possible?